# How to use angular 4 as mini spa in just one or two pages of an application made with asp.net mvc core?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, single-page-application

I do have a very big application built with asp.net core (15 areas like customers, employees, financial, schedule, etc..). I want to create a new area that I would like to use Angular 4. It’s s very dynamic little “mini spa” inside the main already built app.

After reading articles like “[What should be in a Single Page Application?](https://medium.com/@maurice.de.beijer/what-should-be-in-a-single-page-application-9bbbf40c3862)” and much others I’m pretty convinced that build a very large spa (even with lazy loading) is not good a solution for big systems with different areas.

However I don’t know exactly how to use angular4 in just one or two pages of the existent app. All Angular tutorials is for build an app entire in Angular and making just REST calls to the server. I don’t want to build a giant monolithic SPA. It’s really not necessary. How can I create or use angular into some asp.net core views without changes to the server.

I just have an requirement that is to DO NOT change the rest of the pages that is working good with asp.net mvc core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, when I was integrating Angular/SPA into a larger application, I found it easiest to embed the SPA portion into an iframe.

The larger application held base pages and menus and other branding-related structure, but that support structure tended to get in the way of the Angular/SPA code.

By placing the "new philosophy" code in an iframe, I was able to retain the overall branding, but implement the SPA approach.

If you do this, don't forget to make your background color transparent so that you can keep the colors from your larger project :)

Comment: Despite I upvote your answer by creativity I would like to avoid using frames into the app. It doesn’t look very organized

Comment: 'doesn't look organized'?  do you mean how it looks in code, or how it looks in the UI?

Comment: Sorry about the comment. What I really means is that I’m not a fan of using frames. It’s a valid solution however I would like to wait for a few more answers . Thanks

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I get that.  It's a bit of a hack. :)